# How useful it is to convert nan to NaN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am trying to run a code which is already written by someone else. However, I am not sure what's the need to convert `nan` to `NaN`

A piece of code line regarding the issue

```
obs['valuestring'].astype(str).str.strip().mask(obs['valuestring'].isna())
```

The above line code gives an output like this

[image]

But what I feel is the piece of code below should be fine. Isn't it?

```
obs['valuestring'].astype(str).str.strip()
```

and it produces the same output as above but `nan` instead of `NaN`

I understand that `np.nan` is `np.NaN`, so trying to learn is there anything useful with this and am I missing it?

Can you help me understand the need to convert `nan` to `NaN` and when should I do these kind of conversions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difference, because in second have no missing values, but string reperesentation of `NaN` - string `nan`:

```
obs = pd.DataFrame({'valuestring':['a ', np.nan, np.nan]})
print (obs)
  valuestring
0          a 
1         NaN
2         NaN

s = obs['valuestring'].astype(str).str.strip().mask(obs['valuestring'].isna())
print (s)
0      a
1    NaN
2    NaN
Name: valuestring, dtype: object

print (s.isna())
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: valuestring, dtype: bool
```

---

```
s = obs['valuestring'].astype(str).str.strip()
print (s)
0      a
1    nan
2    nan
Name: valuestring, dtype: object

print (s.isna())
0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: valuestring, dtype: bool

print (s.eq('nan'))
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: valuestring, dtype: bool
```